# In Vedas, which Devas and Asuras are purely a Deva or an Asura but not both?

Tags: vedas, gods, rig-veda, asuras

Which Devas in Vedas (mainly Rigveda) are never referred to as Asuras and similarly which Asuras in Vedas (mainly Rigveda) are never referred to as Devas? I need references only from Vedas and nothing else.

Comment: The word Asura has many meanings since the word has changed over time. So when the Vedas say Agni etc. is an "Asura", it doesn't mean to say Agni etc. is a demon.